# Quiero ver los datos de un documento excel en un gridview en c# . net

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo este código que gurda el excel en la aplicación  pero al momento de querer consultar los datos no me muestra los datos en el gridview

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

public partial class Agregarexel : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            string savePath = @"C:\Users\SISTEMAS 231118\Documents\minicrm\ArchivosExcel\";

            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = Server.HtmlEncode(FileUpload1.FileName);
                string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.ms-excel" ||
                    FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")
                {


                    savePath += fileName;
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
                    //mensajeError(savePath);

                    //string conexionOLEBD = "provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = '" + savePath + "'; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0; ";
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
                    System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
                    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
                    MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = '" + savePath + "'; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;");
                    MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Hoja1$]", MyConnection);
                    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");
                    DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
                    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
                    GridView1.DataSource = DtSet;
                    MyConnection.Close();

                }    
            }
            else
            {
                mensajeError("Solo se permite  archivos excel ");    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            mensajeError("Error" + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: En esta línea `catch (Exception ex)` ¿tiene algún error?, si es así, [edit] la pregunta para agregar la descripción completa del error.

Comment: no de echo no me sale ninguna excepción

Comment: Francisco, esta línea `GridView1.DataSource = DtSet;` ¿el DtSet tiene datos? si es así, [edit] la pregunta con el código del `GridView1`.

Comment: porque usas `MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable");` eso no aplica

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema que observo es que la ruta al archivo tiene espacios en el nombre cuando defines la carpeta `SISTEMAS 231118`, deberias definir una ruta dentro del sitio web y no en cualquier carpeta, mas que nada por temas de seguridad.

Para unir carpetas usa

```
savePath = Path.Combine(savePath , fileName);
```

El codigo deberia se mas prolijo, usando algo como ser

```
string connstring = "provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " + savePath + "; Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;";
using(OleDbConnection MyConnection = new OleDbConnection(connstring))
{
    OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Hoja1$]", MyConnection);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    MyCommand.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Pero aconsejaria que la ruta sea dentro del sitio, para lo cual deberias tener una carpeta dentro del sitio como ser `UploadExcel` entonces utilizas

```
string uploadExcelPath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadExcel");
string uploadExcelFile = Path.Combine(uploadExcelPath , FileUpload1.FileName);

FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
```

asi tendras la ruta fisica dentro del sitio donde sabes que la seguridad aplicara de forma correcta

Recuerda definir

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

asi el codigo no se hace tan largo